# Spring Boot project - sometime data disappears from PostgreSQL Database

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data

I have been working with a Startup project from Scratch for around 2 year and this is my first project. The project is quite complex with many business logiсs and have thousands of lines of code.

One of the function of the project is that people can place their items on the map to show them to other people who can collect these items. The owners of these items can edit them by editing the name, description and also change the item location in map. Everything works fine when I test in the development server and in the production server.

But, sometimes, when our client is editing the location of the items in the map, server couldn't save the location at Database and the location list of this item becomes empty (I, myself, can't reproduce this error). I am trying hard to figure out the cause for this issue, unfortunately I could not find the bug.

I have tried these function to save the location of the item,

```
locationRepository.save()
locationRepository.saveAndFlush()
```

but all are in vain. From time to time, the error is being shown up and the item's location list becomes empty. Probably it worth noting that there are many lines of code in the location edition function to check item number and their costs and some other necessary checking.

There is not any high load in the server so that server could break down.

Could it be that there is some relation between the Spring Boot version or PostgreSQL version? Or it's a bug in my code which I failed to find.

- **PostgreSQL version: 10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)**
- **Spring Framework version : 2.1.1.**
- **Java version: openjdk 11.0.10**

If you would have any thoughts, ideas, or insights regarding to this issue, please share them.

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you tried to turn on JPA SQL logging, to see the SQL statements generated and sent to the database, and identify when any DELETE query is issued with which parameters ? Depending on your app usage it may be very verbose though.

Comment: @Yann39, thanks for your comment, 
No, I didn't try this. I will follow your advice.

Comment: Usually this kind of unwanted deletion happens when you save an entity improperly populated (missing data) which then can propagates any cascade deletes. But you mentioned that "the error is being shown up", do you have any idea what the error message looks like?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe,  at Yann39,  actually there isn't any error message being shown up. By "error" I mean the data inconsistency in database that the data is not being saved in the database without showing error message.